# How to find the events used by WPR Graph "Power"

Tags: c#, c++, msdn, wpa, wpr

I am using wpr tool to trace "Power". Since etl file size is very large, I am creating custom wpr profile to filter out the interested events.

Under the WPR Graph "Power", We have certain graphs like CPU idle states, Processor utility, Processor Peformance, Processor Frequency etc.)

Lets say i need only one graph "Processor Frequency" and i am creating custom profile for it.

Can anyone help how to create profile for only "Processor Frequency" graph and also any way to find the events used by "Processor Frequency" graph